# How to return the path of typo3conf?

Tags: php, path, typo3

In my file 'class.tx_freephpcoders_pi1.php' I am using the code `require_once('contents/page_683.php');`. Anyway, this is not working for me. I guess I have to return the path of my extension.

This is how my FTP looks like:

[image: FTP]

So how can I get the path of the directory typo3conf?

Comment: `require_once(__DIR__.'/contents/page_683.php');`

Comment: @ksno thank you very much, that's the answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use one of TYPO3 constants like:

```
require_once(PATH_typo3conf.'ext/free_php_code_rs/pi1/contents/foo.php');
```

but better use TYPO3's methods which returns the absolute path to the extension with extension key (after their checking), like:

```
require_once(t3lib_extMgm::extPath('free_php_code_rs').'pi1/contents/bar.php');
```

and for TYPO3 ver. 6+ the same is:

```
require_once(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('free_php_code_rs').'pi1/contents/baz.php');
```

Comment: Thank you! Good to know about that.